# Firebase RTDB read deny response

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Looking for a way to show the user a permission denied message from Firebase when their access has been revoked. In the log I can see the path and denied message ([Firebase/Database][I-RDB038012] Listener at  failed: permission_denied), but I don't know how to get that to the user.

I guess it'd be the read equivalent of `updadeChildValues(_:withCompletionBlock:)` - for an `observe` or `observeSingleEvent` read of the database.

I've tried my own completion block for the likes of

```
if snapshot.exists {
print("exists")
} else {
print("does not exist")
```

But with no luck...Using Swift with Firebase Realtime Database. Quite new, apologies if my terminology is wrong.

Comment: There's a good answer already but I think the question needs some clarity; *when their access has been revoked* - what process are you using to revoke their access? More importantly, when or how do you want the user to be notified of that? When they attempt to authenticate? Or after they authenticate and attempt to read/write data Or perhaps as soon at that happens via a notification? And when access is revoked is that access to everything or just some things?

Comment: Thanks, yes this has been answered now. In response it's after they have authenticated and while using the app. rules have if statements referencing another database node on who can access what and if they can read or write. It a user is using the app and mid-session has their permission changed by another user / admin then the app won't respond to this change. It's an edge case but one I'm hung up on fixing rather than working on more pressing matters :-)

Comment: Glad the answer helped. *the app won't respond to this change* - it could respond to that change if you coded it that way. e.g. If a user has their permission changed while using the app, a view or window could display letting the user know about the change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for `observe(_:with:withCancel:)`. In this overload, you pass in a second callback block, that is invoked when the listener is cancelled (typically because it lacks permission to read).

See
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/DatabaseQuery#observe_:with:withcancel:

For an example of this, see the code snippet on the documentation on [reading data with an observer](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write#read_data_once_with_an_observer).

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly it. I'll do better at looking at the online documentation, in my weak defense when Xcode gave me the list of options  `observe(_:with:withCancel:)` the short description say  _...except the block is immediately canceled after the initial data is returned_. That's on me for giving up easily, thanks for your response!

Comment: That sounds more like the description for the **single-value** listener. If not, please file feedback on the docs page, as that'd be wrong.